# Redirect Docker container logs to host /var/log

Tags: docker, logging

Is there a configuration where we can automatically redirect a container's logs to a file in the host's `/var/log/`? We can access a containers logs using `docker logs` and on the host in `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/`, but we want to access the logs in a file in `/var/log/`. We also want to preserve and append to this file if the container is recreated.

Comment: A possible solution, in the form of a logging driver plugin would be this: https://github.com/deep-compute/docker-file-log-driver (although it seems it is not really maintained)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do what we want. I assume plugin uses the hosts ```/var/log/```? Is the log file appended to if the container is recreated?

Answer (score 1):

We ended up mounting the hosts's `/var/log/` onto a directory in the container and wrote to a file there. We append to the file. The file is visible in `/var/log/` on the host.